# Having two versions of Python installed and installing a new module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two installations of Python on my machine:

- 1 : Python 2.7 32 bits (c:\python27)    (installed first)
- 2 : Python 2.7 64 bits (c:\python27-64)    (installed more recently, **not** setup as system's default Python)

When I install a new package with its standard Windows installer (e.g. `wxPython3.0-win64-3.0.0.0-py27.exe` for `wxPython`), there is no question like :

*"For which installation of Python do you want to install this module?"*

Then this module is not recognized by my second Python install.

**How to deal with module package installation when two versions of Python are installed ?**

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you have both the 32 and 64 bit builds of the same version of python installed on your machine?

Comment: because I need to test on both platforms for final user which might use both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An installer for `win64` and `py27` will automatically try to find the 64-bit Python 2.7 installation and install it for that. It won’t try to install it for an incompatible Python installation.

For package installations via pip etc., you just need to call the correct one to install it for that version. So `C:\python27\Scripts\pip.exe` or `C:\python27-64\Scripts\pip.exe` in your case.